# Best way to transfer files from 3rd party device to iOS app

Tags: ios, iphone, bluetooth, gps, mfi

What is the best way to transfer files from 3rd party device (that I want to build) to iOS app (that I want to create)?

The device will generate data which will be processed by this iOS app and presented afterwards.

This device will be some kind of GPS logger - tens of megabytes.

- Can I use Bluetooth PAN initiated and handled completly by the iOS app?
- Can I make WiFi direct connection initiated and handled completly by the iOS app?
- For this solution I need MFI program enrollment?